# Apache Flink: Is there a way to know the retry count in asyncInvoke() api while using async retry strategies?

Tags: asynchronous, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am bit stuck in finding how can I get the current retry count in async I/O operator using async retry strategies?
Also which api gets invoked when retry count exceeds the set limit? And to override it, so that we can hook in some custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

there is a doc that describes that [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=211883963). I think at the moment there is no way to get the attempt count for the particular operator.

I think that once the jobs times out or fails the `AsyncFunction.timeout()` is called, so You can hook up Your code there to make sure some default result is produced.

Comment: I have handled timeout() but my interest area is retry, because in my business logic I have to retry like 3 times & post that i need to send error event on stream(topic).

Hence it is important to know when retries are over.

Comment: I don't think that's possible currently. What You can try to do is to implement a custom `AsyncRetryStrategy` that will delay retry after 3rd failure so that function hits timeout and You can handle that in `timeout()` method. But that may be a little tricky to get right.